# ¿Porqué este try catch no funciona de la forma correcta?

Tags: c#, mysql, try-catch

EL problema es que cada vez que quiero ingresar algo a mi base de datos, primero me da el mensaje de error, y al volverlo a presionar si guarda el registro. Siempre pasa al iniciar la aplicación. A la hora de presionar guardar, primero me tira el mensaje del catch aunque no esté malo y luego al cerrarlo y volver a presionar el botón de guardar, si me tira el mensaje dentro del try.

```
    try 
        {
            string agregar = "insert into usuarios values('" + txtIDUsuario.Text + "'," + "md5('" + TxtContraseña.Text + "'), 'md5',' " + TipoUsuario + "','" + txtNombresUsuarios.Text + "','" + txtApellidosUsuario.Text + "','" + fechaComoQuiero + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(txtNumeroUsuario.Text) + "','" + txtCorreoUsuario.Text + "','" + rtxtRedSocialUsuario.Text + "','" + rtxtDireccionUsuario.Text + "');";
            if (con.insertar(agregar))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Datos agregados");
                //mostrarDatos();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error al agregar. Contacte al proveedor");
            mostrarDatos();
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Desconectar();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Para saber el porqué, debes examinar los detalles de la excepción que causa que se ejecute el bloque `catch`. Incluye esos detalles en tu pregunta. Pero te puedo decir de una vez que no es buena idea que estés concatenando todos tus valores directamente en la cadena SQL. Sé que ya lo mencioné en otra pregunta tuya, pero lo seguiré repitiendo. Te expones a varios problemas.

Comment: A penas estoy iniciando, y por ahora esto me es funcional porque priorizo en base al tiempo de entrega del proyecto y requisitos simplones. Protegerlo de ataques se que es imprescindible cuándo se trata de un trabajo profesional, pero los requisitos son otros en este caso, la seguridad sale sobrando (ámbito académico). De igual forma agradezco esa insistencia, investigaré como hacerlo mediante parámetros.

Comment: Basándome en el comportamiento que describes y tu código, el culpable de eso tan raro que dices puede estar en el método `mostrarDatos()` porque el `catch` lo lanza y debe hacer algo que hace que funcione a la segunda, pero sin el código no podemos saberlo.

Comment: Segun lo que describes puede ser que el error sea con tu variable `con` ya que a la primera vez cae en el `catch` y luego en el `finally` por lo tanto tu variable `con` cierra la conexión a tu base de datos. Revisa tu codigo anteriormente si abres la conexion y no la cierras debuggea. Para tu suerte visual studio tiene herramientas para debuggear muy buenas pon puntos de interrupcion. Por otro lado la manera en que trabajar los datos y los insert puede que funcionen pero ¿por que no ocupar lo potente del ide? Busca como trabajar con la base de datos hay muchas clases que te ayudan. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Sea cual sea la razón la excepción que te esté dando, que como te han dicho antes los compañeros, con esta información es complicado saberlo, deberías de añadir por lo menos un tipo a tu excepción para poder debuguear los datos y tener algún tipo de pista del error, algo así:

```
try 
    {
        string agregar = "insert ...";

        if (con.insertar(agregar))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Datos agregados");
            //mostrarDatos();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        string mensajeError = ex.message;

        /// Aquí puedes saber que tipo de excepción es, y el pq de esta,
        /// A veces es importante mirar el innerexception.

        MessageBox.Show("Error al agregar. Contacte al proveedor");
        mostrarDatos();
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Desconectar();
    }
}
```

Después podrás crear partes catchs especializadas según cada error.

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente estas cosas pueden ocurrir cuando obtienes un error en la base de datos (si se viola alguna clave única, por ejemplo. A mí me ha pasado cuando la lógica que está por encima de esto borra o inserta algún tipo de registro previo.

Lo mejor sería ver la consulta generada y reproducirla en un cliente de base de datos para ver el error que te obtienes.

Al margen de eso, un par de cosas que podrías mirar más adelante son:

- No utilizar excepciones para manejar el código. Una excepción es que la conexión a base de datos falle porque el servidor esté caído, pero no que la consulta falle porque tenga datos repetidos. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why
- No utilizar "ñ" en los nombres de variables. Sé que estamos en épocas modernas ya, pero es algo que prefiero no hacer.
- Lo que te comentan acerca de la seguridad, aunque sea ámbito académico, estaría bien verlo porque luego no te lleva mucho más tiempo verlo.